# SharePoint SOAP Request always sends back WSDL

Tags: sharepoint, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to read lists from a SharePoint 2007 server. I first tried saaj, and am now trying axis2.  With debugging turned on, I see that I am getting back the contents of the WSDL every time I make a valid request.  I'm using tcpmon to fake requests and modify them.  When I change them, I get errors.

Why am I getting the wsdl back as a response?  Shouldn't I be getting back a valid response soap envelope?

Endpoint:

```
https://internal.mycompany.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL
```

Request:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:GetListCollection xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, remove the '?WSDL' from the endpoint, and it starts working. Before it worked, I had to first smack my forehead and then shake my fist at all the articles that indicate the endpoint includes '?WSDL'